# Java: Searching text for Multiple Occurrences

Tags: java, search

Q: If I were given an exorbitantly large filled with random English words and were told to find specific sub-strings cut by a whitespace [For example, "how now", "brown cow", etc.], and then return the position at which it appears, how would I do it?

A: I have a partial solution, but I'm asking the Stack Overflow community for help completing the last bit.

**How Program Should Run:**

- Give program a text file
- Searches through the entire file
- Returns line number and word number; the word number is in relation to line
- If "how now" is found as the first two words of two consecutive lines, it would return "how now" found on line k at position 1, and found once again on line k+1 at position 1 as well.
- If the line is "how now the count of monte brown cow cristo", then it should be able to detect "how now" and "brown cow" as two separate occurrences.

**Solution 1:**

```
int chn = 0;
int cbc = 0;

Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("filename.txt"));
String temp = in.nextLine();

Pattern phn = Pattern.compile("how now");
Pattern pbc = Pattern.compile("brown cow");
Matcher mhn = null;
Matcher mbc = null;

while (in.hasNext()) {

    mhn = phn.matcher(temp);
    while (mhn.find()) m++;

    mbc = pbc.matcher(temp);
    while (mbc.find()) j++;

    temp = in.nextLine();
} // Formatted output comes after
```

The thing is while this keeps track of the number of occurrences (chn, cbc) by using Patterns and Matchers and also keeps track of chronological occurrence, and is the fastest algorithm in doing so, I'm at a loss for how I can keep track of where in the line it occurs.

**Solution 2:**

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("filename.txt"));
ArrayList<String> wordsInLine = new ArrayList<>();
String temp = in.nextLine();
String temp2 = "";

ctL = 1;

while (in.hasNext()) { 
    if (temp.contains("how now")) {
        for (String word : temp.split(" ")) {
            wordsInLine.add(word);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < wordsInLine.size(); i++) {
            if (wordsInLine.get(i).equals("how") || 
                wordsInLine.get(i + 1).equals("now")) {

                System.out.println("This returns line count and "
                    + "the occurrence by getting i");
            }
        }
    }

    ctL++;
    temp = in.nextLine();
}
```

But this second partial solution seems incredibly inefficient and terribly slow, using two for loops for every line that contains "how now."
Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Why are you conducting your search in a single thread? You could speed up the process by performing each search independently. Since all you are doing is reading an input file, you can have simultaneous readers without having to worry about collisions.

Comment: Why use regex instead of simply doing `indexOf()`?

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1 is definitely much more efficient and I would go for that approach for sure.

In order to keep track of the position of the matched pattern in a specific line, you can use the [`start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start()) or the [`end()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#end()) method of the [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class to get the corresponding indices.

Comment: while (mm.find()) {
                    posm = mm.start();
                    posm++;
                    System.out.println("Line: " + lct + 
                            " Position: " + posm + " " + mm.group());
                    m++;
                }
I tested it on a small file I made myself and it works perfectly, except if I throw in a twist, say:

Line 1: abc def ghi foo
Line 2: bar jkl mno pqr

Would there be any way of counting that as occurring on Line 1, position 4, that doesn't brute force check every next line?

Appreciate the help so far; thanks again, in advance x

Comment: There are many ways to handle this issue, but I think the most straight forward modification would be to match the pattern on the concatenation of line `i` and line `i + 1` during the `i`-th iteration. This will give us two matches when there is an exact match on a single line, but only one of these matches is meaningful and the other case can be easily discarded by considering criteria such as the length of line `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Go with Solution 1. Use start, end and group methods to track subsequence matched:

```
mhn = phn.matcher(temp);

while (mhn.find()) {
    System.out.print(mhn.start() + ", ");
    System.out.print(mhn.end() + ", ");
    System.out.println(mhn.group());
    m++;
}
```